# How can I assign all the UIImageViews in view to a image of a star?

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, subviews

I need assign all the UIImageViews with a width of 17 pixels in a view and all the subviews to an image of a star.

I was trying this:

```
for v in view.subviews {
        let view = v as! UIImageView
        if view.frame.width == 17 {
        view.image = UIImage (named: "star.jpg")
        }

    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'...

Comment: I know, why it doesn't work. ) How could it be solved?

Comment: You know why it doesn't work... so explain to us. Also, what does `doesn't work` mean? Does the app crash? Is there an error message? Are all the images upside down? Are all the images actually of elephants and not stars? Does your phone set on fire? There are infinitely many ways that this can `not work`.

Comment: I did:) Please check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38372095/4534690

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have added imageview to self.view as subiew.

```
 for subView in self.view.subviews {
            if subView.isKindOfClass(UIImageView)
            {
                let subImgView = subView as! UIImageView
                if subImgView.frame.width == 17 {
                    subImgView.image = UIImage (named: "star.jpg")
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
     if let img = view as? UIImage {
           image.image = UIImage (named: "star.jpg")
     }
}
```